# How to create values folder for specific resolutions

Tags: android-layout, android

I would like to create values folders for some specific resolutions(devices).

AFAIK, i can create values folders as like;

- values-sw320dp-hdpi
- values-sw480dp
- ...

  I need device specific values folders, for example, Note 4 devices 5.7'' 2560x1440 xxhdpi how can i create a values folder for that device one more example could be very useful let's say 10.1'' 2560x1600 xhdpi device. How values folders should be named ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if having value folders with the specific resolution is possible.

But a different solution could be to get the screen resolution like this:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)   
getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);   
than using the activity context object or the getWindowManager() shortcut
wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
int screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
```

And then have  a switch statement set a layout in your onCreate.

Comment: okay whatever dude.. Probably should be open to another approach though

Comment: Well i look at your code now, but i don't have issue with switching layouts i had trouble with getting correct values folder but i solved it as i mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a way but i'm not sure if it makes sense ;

Note 4 devices 5.7'' 2560x1440 xxhdpi = it's 854x480dp in mdpi space so, **values-sw480dp-xxhdpi** works fine. I'll keep that approach for now i how i can find a more specific way to do that.